# Telnet Client switching from CMD.EXE to COMMAND.COM

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, windows-server-2008, telnet

I have configured a **telnet server in a Windows Server 2008 Host Computer**. 
(I use W2008 because I'm running a 16 bit DOS application, and only Windows 2008 made its installation successful)

**I successfully connected to the server via my Windows 10 telnet client.**
But when I want to change the keyboard language in french (`AZERTY`), I use this command:

```
kb16 fr
```

It works well.
To understand what is `kb16`: [MS-DOS and Windows command line keyb command [Computer Hope]](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/2/1563289834-screen.jpg)

But it suddenly changed the style of the command prompt, **and I saw that it's no more `CMD.EXE` style  but `COMMAND.COM` style.**
Here a screenshot:
[image: <code>kbd</code> screenshot]

So why is that a problem to me? With AZERTY, **I need to use Alt Gr touch** for example to have the backslash (Alt Gr 8). But when I try Alt Gr 8 on that `COMMAND.COM`, it gives me `_`.

Even `ALT+92` command doesn't work.

Do you know how to fix this?

---

**EDIT:**
 I'm opening Windows Server 2008 with VirtualBox, and it's hosting my telnet server. The `COMMAND.COM` comes from that Windows Server 2008. I don't know why but there are two types of Command Prompt, see this screen:
[image: <code>cmd</code> screenshot]

And I tried your command, the `EXIT` command worked ! Here the screen:
[image: <code>exit</code> screenshot]

---

**EDIT 2:** 
I tried the [`chcp` command](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html).
My code is 850. So I do `chcp 850` to set the page code to 850.

When I do `exit` and I write `chcp`
The `COMMAND.COM` is indeed set to page code 850.
So I can `\\\\` in the COMMAND.COM. But when I run my 16-bit DOS application, it doesn't take effect.

But I ran a `Windows 10 32 bits` server and run my 16-bit application, and I meet no problems with the `\` when I put `ALT+92`.
So it should normally work...

Comment: Please don't link to external images, upload them by [edit]ing your question and using the *Image <img>* (*Ctrl+G*) button! Anyway, what you see are [short filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). By the way: what's `kb16`?

Comment: Edited. Kb16 is a command for MS-DOS to set keyboard language. 
Here a link to see the reference : https://www.computerhope.com/keybhlp.htm

       For example, doing  kb16 fr  will set french keyboard (Azerty).

Comment: So `kb16` is the same as `keyb`? I read up-to-date Windows versions in your question, so I have no clue where `COMMAND.COM` should come from; have you tried to type `quit` or `bye`? what happens then?

Comment: I've edited the question to demonstrate what I meant with my initial comment concerning the screenshot images. Concerning your first edit: my soggestion of `quit` and `bye` was intended to find out whether you really are in the Windows Command Prompt (`cmd`) or in some other console, but apparently you are.

Comment: Concerning the snapshots of the `cmd` property windows: the left window shows the properties of `cmd.exe` while the right one shows those of a **link** (`.lnk`) to `cmd.exe`; switch to the *Shortcut* tab to view the properties of the link target `cmd.exe`; anyway, both show Windows Command Prompt but **not an MS-DOS `COMMAND:COM` console**!

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, I see now, i was wrong indeed. It still doesn't explain the problem, but have a look at this screenshot please. In `cmd` I wrote `dir %windir%\System32\*.com` 

I have this : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/3/1563366772-screen.jpg
(I meet problems editing my post)

Comment: I think the problem comes from telnet. Have a look a this picture, i've run the same program (one in cmd.exe from windows 2008, one from telnet), so the two windows should do the same things. When I `Alt Gr + 8 `, it gives `"\"` in Windows 2008, but it gives `"_"` in my telnet client. 
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/3/1563368978-comparaison.jpg

Comment: Strange... anyway, it should be `keyb fr` but not `keybfr`...

Comment: Yes, you're right. But that `keybfr` is actually a program made by a french user which changes that `keyb` parameter. http://www.win3x.org/win3board/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=718&sid=a7fbe27bfea386376d0641bbd26fa27f
 
About my problem, I changed telnet client software, and now `Alt Gr +  8` works fine, but those clients can't open my DOS application. I'm still testing each telnet client software one by one to resolve this.

Comment: After days of research, I arrived to one conclusion : I think that the `AltGr` button doesn't exist in any 16-bit DOS Application. The only way to put `"\"` is to do Alt+92.
I hope someone one day will prove otherwise. Thanks for your help aschipfl ! You can set "solved"

Comment: Well, in MS-DOS *Alt Gr* existed as it was needed to enter pipes `|` in German keyboards, for instance; perhaps it is a problem with one of these keyboard layout tools `kb16` or `keybfr`? Anyway, I cannot mark this as solved, the only one that can do that is *you*, as soon as you provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) then...

Comment: Ok, I'll keep work on it. I've tested each chcp page code, changed nothing.